# JAXB2 fails to generate sources from two WSDLs that have duplicate types

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use JAXB2 2.2 to generate sources from WSDL files. The WSDL files come from a third party and they all define the same common types in addition to a type specific to that WSDL. If I have only one WSDL in the source folder (let's call it A.wsdl), everything works great and the generated sources look like:

> A.java 
>  X.java
>  Y.java

If I clear the output dir and generate with only B.wsdl I get

> B.java 
> X.java 
> Y.java

I want to be able to put both WSDLs in the source and get

> A.java
>  B.java
>  X.java
>  Y.java

I don't care which wsdl X and Y come from, they are identical for all of them. Currently JAXB2 throws `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 'X' is already defined` and generates nothing. I went through the help output but didn't find any config options that seemed like they would help.

Comment: Why are you generating the classes inside the same package? This can't work. What if `X` from WSDL1 and `X` from WSDL2 aren't the same? Also, please post exactly the command you are using or Maven configuration.

Comment: Also very related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274407/prevent-generation-of-duplicate-classes-from-xsds-without-namespaces

Comment: @Tunaki I'm running `mvn jaxb2:xjc`
X is the same for both WSDLs in my business case. I'm basically looking for some way to just tell JAXB to ignore or overwrite duplicates.

Comment: Oh, and my config is very barebone `<configuration><sources>
      <source>src/main/wsdl/</source>
     </sources>
     <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType></configuration>`

Comment: Have you looked at the linked question? It was answered by the developer of the library himself.

Comment: I did, but he clearly says "this isn't an answer to your question" in the first and last lines of his answer. I'll try his binding suggestion, although it's unfortunate that I have to spell out every duplicate class instead of just telling JAXB to ignore any dupes it runs across.